# Manually insert values in asp ListView rows using a template view and finally add all the ListView rows to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, listbox

I have a textbox, a listbox and a listview in asp.net page. I will enter a name in textbox and press `button_add` then it will be inserted into the listbox. This way i can add any number of names or delete them using another button `button_delete`. The code i use the below code for this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button_add" runat="server" Text="Add Name" OnClick="button_add_Click" />
<asp:ListBox ID="list_name" SelectionMode="Single" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="button_delete" runat="server" Text="Delete Name" OnClick="button_delete_Click" />

protected void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = list_name.Items.Count;
    list_name.Items.Insert(count, new ListItem(text_name.Text, new ListItem(text_name.Text));
    text_name.Text = "";
}

protected void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list_name.Items.RemoveAt(list_name.Items.IndexOf(list_name.SelectedItem));
    // all books related to this person should be deleted from listview
}
```

This one is working fine. Next i want to have list of books studied by each person and each of the book has three attributes like `page_number` which is integer, `book_type` which is a dropdownlist selection and `published_year` which is also integer. After i add a person to the listbox i can click a particulat person and then press `button_addbook` to add a book for that person. As soon as i click the add book button a template should appear in below format,

```
label_personname     text_bookpages     text_bookpublishyear    droplist_booktype
```

And from here i can enter the specific values for that book. Then when i select a different person from listbox and press add book button the same should happen. Also i can add multiple books for same person and for each time a new row should appear for this. And if i delete a person from the listbox, then all the books related to that person should be deleted from the book list.

I am trying to use listview for the purpose of displaying all the book rows where i can enter the book details. I have tried the following.

```
<asp:ListView ID="listview_books" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="label_personname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PersonName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_bookpages" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BookPages") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="list_booktype" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("BookType") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Novel" Value="Novel"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Studies" Value="Studies"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_publishedyear" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BookYear") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:Button ID="button_addbook" runat="server" Text="Add Name" OnClick="button_addbook_Click" />

protected void button_addbook(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // A new listview row should be created with the person name selected in listbox added in the label_personname and the remaining three fields should displayed empty so i can enter values in them.
}
```

Finally after entering all person and their books i will have a final submit button that will get all values rows the listview and add add it into a database table.

I am still new to listview and i dont know how to work in that. Can someone help  me out with this?

Comment: Not a answer to your question, but I would highly recommend using Razor view engine instead of aspx. Maybe you cannot do it in this project, but consider it in the next ;)

Comment: Oh ok ok sure thank you :) Yes i have already done 90% of the webpage only this page is left so i cannot switch